# NullPointerException when call one instance method from other method of the same object

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

A see in Crashlytics that I have NullPointerException when call one instance method from the same object instance method.

Crash happens on this line `for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {`  with error `ActivityMain$c.getCount()' on a null object reference`

```
public class ActivityMain extends BaseActivity {

    private MainPagerAdapter adapter; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        adapter.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public void onDestroy() {
            for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) { // ActivityMain$c.getCount()' on a null object reference
                BasePagerFragment item = getItem(i);
                destroyItem(item);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return User.getCurrentUser().isAdmin() ? 3 : 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Crash happens when onDestroy() called. How it's possible?

Comment: where is `//initialized in onCreate()`

Comment: I'm assuming that `ActivityMain` has already been destroyed/GC'd by the time that method is being called.

Comment: @ScaryWombat added to example